# Accessibility talkback issue with select and option tag

Tags: javascript, accessibility, talkback

I need a help with talkback android reader on Select Option tag. It is working fine with nvda and jaws but talkback is somehow not reading aria-label text in option tag

```
<select aria-label='test' id="cars">
  <option aria-label="test1">Volvo </option>
  <option aria-label="test2">Saab </option>
  <option aria-label="test3">Mercedes</option>
  <option aria-label="test4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This is the piece of code i have in react. NVDA react test1, test2, when focus on option with keyboard up and down arrow key. but somehow it is not reading test1 , test2 when focus on option on mobile with talkback.It reads Volvo, saab etc instead.

Comment: One possible workaround is to use `option title="test1" aria-label="test1">Volvo </option> and so on`. Can you check if this works for your case?

Comment: tried already. didnt work

Comment: thanks. Can you also please add in your questions what things you tried? It'll help to suggest other probable solutions